# Adding a light to existing circuit

Tags: lighting

I have a light in my garage and I am trying to add two new recessed lights. Currently the light has power running directly to it as well as the switch wires. When I tried to wire it. The new lights got power but could not be controlled by the switch. They wouldnt turn off. I am stuck and could really use some help.
[image]

Comment: Can you insert a picture of the switch into your question, so we can see how it's wired?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what we are looking at. Is this the original wiring connected to the existing fixture and the NM to the left and off screen the new wiring to the new cans? Or is this your attempt to rewire the old fixture? Also FYI you need to clean up the ground wire, try to retwist it again and put a wire nut on it.